# Move points into center of polygons base on common field attributes using QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I have a shapefile of points and polygons layers with a common field attribute "Parcel_No". Each of the points share a common unique "Parcel_No" with the polygons, but the points are outside the polygons. I need an expression to move the points into the polygons base on the common field attribute (Parcel_No) using QGIS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More details would be needed, but here's a prime example:
through the use of QGIS expressions:

```
closest_point(
   geometry(get_feature('polygon','Parcel_No',
   attribute( $currentfeature, 'Parcel_No' ))),
   $geometry)
```

the expression plots, for each point and following the Parcel_No attribute, the point closest to the corresponding polygon.[image]

Or

with the points collected around a circumference

```
with_variable('geomPolygon', 
  geometry(
     get_feature('polygon',
                 'Parcel_No',
                  attribute( $currentfeature, 'Parcel_No' ))),
closest_point(buffer(centroid(
   @geomPolygon), bounds_height((@geomPolygon))/5),
   $geometry))
```

[image]

To move all points in the centroid of its polygon:

[image]

```
with_variable('geomPolygon', 
  geometry(
    get_feature('polygon',
                'Parcel_No',
                 attribute($currentfeature, 'Parcel_No'))),
  closest_point(
    centroid(@geomPolygon),
    $geometry))
```

Moves the points within the polygons and distributes them randomly around its centroid:

[image]

```
--> variabile
with_variable('geomPolygon', 
    geometry(
    get_feature('polygon',
            'Parcel_No',
             attribute( $currentfeature, 'Parcel_No' ))),
--> variabile
project(
point:=
    closest_point(
    geometry1:=centroid(@geomPolygon), -- polygon
    geometry2:=$geometry), -- point
distance:=
    distance(
    closest_point(
    boundary(@geomPolygon),centroid(@geomPolygon)),
    centroid(@geomPolygon))*randf(0,1),
azimuth:=
    radians (rand(0,360))
    )
)
```

Comment: Very clever!  Perhaps a variation where the incoming points were randomly distributed throughout each polygon? Or to each centroid?

Comment: also added the case that moves all points in the centroid of its polygon

Comment: @pigreco. Wow,Wow Wow!!!!!!!!! the expressions really works. Thanks alot. am looking forward to learn more from you.

Comment: I added the case where it shifts them inside the polygons randomly

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Virtual Layers`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?#creating-virtual-layers) and SQL Queries:

```
SELECT pt.Parcel_No,closestpoint(st_centroid(pl.geometry),
                    pt.geometry) as geom /*:point:3857*/
FROM point pt, polygon pl
where pt.Parcel_No = pl.Parcel_No
```

[image]
[image]