# Select points and move points into center of polygons based on common field attributes using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, expression

I have two vector files: Points and Polygon in shapefile format. I need to know how many points lie outside the boundary of the polygons. And how many are located inside each polygon. After that, I need to move those points, that are outside the polygons, into the center of their nearest polygon without affecting the points which are positioned correctly.

From this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425911/move-points-into-center-of-polygons-base-on-common-field-attributes-using-qgis), it works for me both codes but I did not able to select only the points which are outside the boundaries. How can I move only points that are out of their polygon and do not touch the points within?

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

Comment: You can use the 'select by location' tool.

Comment: Which method would you like to use to move the points outside the polygons to inside the nearest polygon? By moving them manually?
Which criteria would you use to define which points outside the polygon would go inside which polygon? Proximity only?

Comment: Your question title "move points into center of polygons based on common field attributes.." doesnt match the description "move those points, that are outside the polygons, into the center of their nearest polygon". -1